# Call Javascript Function with multi-line string from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, d3.js, uiwebview

I am using `D3.js` to create a chart for some information in the form of a TSV File. I have the TSV file saved as a NSString. In the javascript I have a function that will take the string, parse it, and create a chart based on its contents. Here is my code for calling the `JS` function:

```
[self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"parseTSV(\"%@\");", tsvString]];
```

The function is never called in the above code, but it is if I pass in a random string literal like this:

```
[self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"parseTSV(\"randomString\")"];
```

Is this possibly because `JS` doesn't take a string with multiple lines as a function argument? Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support the newline *character* in string literals - it doesn't matter if it's an argument to a function or not. Encode the newline as `"\n"` or, better, use an existing appropriate escape mechanism (a JSON string would work suitably well).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the newline character is already encoded as `\n` already...

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a SyntaxError (which is the most plausible explanation of the behavior) - a string is a string is a string. It doesn't matter from where, as long as it's a valid expression. I would recommend using JSON here (and just pass an entire object, with strings as some values) - this will avoid any trivial parsing errors such as "newlines in strings" and easily accommodate the expansion of more complex values/data. (There are other cases where "randomString" could break JS: i.e. certain backslash combinations or double quotes.)

Comment: Thank You for you help. I needed to change the newline character in the string (`"\n"`) to `"\\n"` in order for the JS to recognize it.

Comment: It needs to be `"\n"` *in the JavaScript literal*, but `"\\n"` in a C string literal (which will be `"\n"` in the resulting C string and thus JS literal). While it's good that the immediate problem is solved, I still urge building a stronger interface layer with JSON as the exchange format.